# ActiveX not loaded if page is called by IP

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, lotus-domino

Calling a Lotus Domino form that contain an ActiveX

```
<OBJECT id="DSV" classid="clsid:CBBABF03-D183-11D2-819C-00001C011F1D" align="baseline"         
border="0" width="0" height="0">
</OBJECT>
```

via domain server name (e.g. `http://server-name/db/form?openform`), everything is fine, calling the same page via IP (e.g. `http://10.0.0.151/db/form?openform`), ActiveX doesn't load.

What could be the problem?

I'm working with Windows 8 and IE10

Comment: it might be that it sees 10.0.0.* to be a local ip, and so treats it with different security settings

Comment: yep, it's a LAN IP. How to change security on ActiveX? Through "Internet options" in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem adding address in trusted site (in IE, Internet Options -> Security -> Sites)